# face texture mapping tool

Tags: uv

Are there any free tools that I can use to turn a single image into face diffuse map, displacement map and face normal map? I'm trying to use my own face to create an avatar of myself. And the character creator 4 is too expensive for me

Comment: if you're talking about converting an image into a normal map or a bump map you can do it in Krita or Photoshop or use a site like https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/

Comment: Maybe this helps [How to create a 3D face using a single image and with enhanced texture in Blender](https://youtu.be/ecr_FgFFWgw). [Mb-Lab](https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/) is a free character creator add-on for Blender.